# Background image slider - white space on bottom after changing document height by jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, background, slider, height

I have a page http://www.drevodomecek.cz/katalog-domu/dum/mob-2-a/
**There is an full-screen image background slider(100% x 100% fixed cover).
All is fine, but if I change the height of content without reloading the page by jQuery, on the bottom appears white space.** Please try it on the page above. There is item "Kalkulátor" with SELECT box. After selecting scroll down.
Thank you for an ideas!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC3d6.jpg)

```
body, html {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position: relative;
}
#bgPage {
min-height:100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}
<body>
<div id="bgPage"></div>
dynamic height without reloading page by jQuery
</body>
```

Comment: We can't trust every link on the Internet, please post your code and your screenshots

Comment: Welcome! Please, visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chanses of getting an answer.